# iCloud Core Data iOS 6 to iOS 7 empty local fallback store initially

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, icloud

I'm struggling to find the correct or any good references to my problem with the transition from iOS 6 to iOS 7.

Our iOS 6 app version: Makes use of iCloud, with a local fallback store when iCloud is disabled/unavailable. This iOS 6 version has been used and the iCloud store file populated with rather large amounts of data.

Our iOS 7 app version: Configured with the new iOS 7 iCloud Core Data API. Running this version for the first time shows no of the existing iCloud store's data captured with the iOS 6 version, even though the file exist and contains all of the data. The reason being the new shiny Core Data fallback store is being used and contains none of the existing data. Only after a large time delay the data appears. This is not ideal as it appears as if the user lost their data.

Is there an existing solution to this problem, or should this be handled manually through making use of a different fallback store while the new fallback store is empty and being populated?

Just as a footnote, there are some light weight changes to the model as well. Not sure this empty database is a product of the migration perhaps? Will do a test to see if I can establish this.

Answer (score 0):

The fallback store that is initially provided by Core Data under iOS7 will not be populated with any data from iCloud.  However if the user enters some data before the iCloud store is ready then this data will be migrated to the iCloud store when it becomes available.

If your app is performing a lightweight migration then that's most probably the reason you are seeing the delay.  Once the migration has completed and you restart the app then the startup time should be quite small again.

The other way to test whether the delay is from the migration is by using the old model so no migration is required and seeing if this makes a substantial difference.

Note that the new fallback store does not get populated unless by data entered by your user.

If you observe the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification` and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification` you will be notified when the store is switched.

You might also want to display a message to the user while the upgrade process is happening - i.e. until you get the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification` notification.

Take a look at the WWDC2013 207 session notes and video.

EDIT:
Here is the log of the opening of an iCloud file. This line

```
2013-12-11 10:47:10.794 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] AppDelegate.fileOpened called
```

is called from the UIManagedDocument Open completion handler. So that tells me the UIManagedDocument has successfully opened. At this point I know it's using the local fallback store.
After that I have to wait, sometime for some time, before the next line appears

```
2013-12-11 10:47:11.291 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] AppDelegate.storesDidChange called - >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

This is processing a storesDidChange notification and now I know the app is using the iCloud store. However depending on the device the iCloud store may also still be empty if the device has not yet downloaded and imported any of the logs.  To address this I have a check to see if I can find particular records in the database yet, once they are found I know that the data import has at least progressed to loading the seed data.  I should also mention that I check for the presence of iCloud files before creating the local copy to avoid merge issues.  Obviously if iCloud is off then this is not possible.

```
2013-12-11 10:47:10.290 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] AppDelegate.loadFile called.
2013-12-11 10:47:10.292 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] AppDelegate.managedObjectModel called.
2013-12-11 10:47:10.509 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] AppDelegate. setting merge policy
2013-12-11 10:47:10.545 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] AppDelegate.storesDidChange called - >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2013-12-11 10:47:10.555 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'preferences' on entity 'Details'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.556 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'scope' on entity 'Details'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.558 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'details' on entity 'ExpenseTransaction'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.560 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'details' on entity 'Interface'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.562 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'details' on entity 'Issues'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.564 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'details' on entity 'OpexTransaction'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.568 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'details' on entity 'ProjectNode'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.570 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'details' on entity 'Risks'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.573 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'comments' on entity 'System'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.574 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'functions' on entity 'System'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.578 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'details' on entity 'Timesheet'
2013-12-11 10:47:10.608 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] AppDelegate.storesDidChange called - >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2013-12-11 10:47:10.609 iProject2iOS[5431:5877] -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](754): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~A3BF465A-15C7-46F2-8C68-AC8F49FD15AB:New Project Local_UUID_4D7AFA0C-3C62-452E-8302-6401ED356478
Using local storage: 1
2013-12-11 10:47:10.794 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] AppDelegate.fileOpened called
2013-12-11 10:47:11.291 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] AppDelegate.storesDidChange called - >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2013-12-11 10:47:11.292 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] OpeningViewController.refreshUI: called
2013-12-11 10:47:11.293 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] MenuViewController.refreshUI: called
2013-12-11 10:47:11.294 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] OpeningViewController. about to call displayItem
2013-12-11 10:47:11.295 iProject2iOS[5431:60b] OpeningViewController. displayItem has been called
2013-12-11 10:47:11.649 iProject2iOS[5431:60af] -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](754): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~A3BF465A-15C7-46F2-8C68-AC8F49FD15AB:New Project Local_UUID_4D7AFA0C-3C62-452E-8302-6401ED356478
Using local storage: 0
```

If its a local store being opened then this is the sequence of calls. Because iCloud is not ON I don't expect another storesDidChange notification. I set a flag in the Open completion handler and then when I get a storesDidChange notification I refresh the UI if this flag is set, otherwise I ignore it (if iCloud is ON). If we are not using iCloud I don't need to call refreshUI because the UI is activated by the Open completion handler at which time the local store is available.

```
2013-12-11 10:55:26.255 iProject2iOS[5440:60b] AppDelegate.application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: called
2013-12-11 10:55:26.259 iProject2iOS[5440:60b] AppDelegate.checkUserICloudPreferenceAndSetupIfNecessary called
2013-12-11 10:55:26.460 iProject2iOS[5440:60b] AppDelegate. User preference for au.com.ossh.iProject2.UseICloudStorage is NO
2013-12-11 10:55:26.462 iProject2iOS[5440:60b] AppDelegate. User disabled iCloud
2013-12-11 10:55:26.464 iProject2iOS[5440:60b] AppDelegate. iCloud is active
2013-12-11 10:55:29.977 iProject2iOS[5440:60b] AppDelegate.loadFile called.
2013-12-11 10:55:29.980 iProject2iOS[5440:60b] AppDelegate.managedObjectModel called.
2013-12-11 10:55:30.190 iProject2iOS[5440:60b] AppDelegate. setting merge policy
2013-12-11 10:55:30.231 iProject2iOS[5440:60b] AppDelegate.storesDidChange called - >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2013-12-11 10:55:30.330 iProject2iOS[5440:60b] AppDelegate.fileOpened called
```

Here is a link to some additional detail on [enabling the UI when using Core Data and iCloud](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/when-to-enable-the-user-interface/).

Comment: Appreciate your reply. I watched that video maybe 20 times. The app setup is quite complex causing the NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification to be called a number of times. It is not confined to the local/iCloud store switching. Also, the notification only contains what type of switching took place and a url. I might be wrong but it seems like that url to the store stays the same after switching to the iCloud store. Do you know of any api to use for determining whether local storage is being used? Need this to know when a message should be shown.

Comment: @Schoob no sure the logs above help at all but once UIManagedDocument open completion handler is called the local store is available. Subsequent storesDidChange are the switch to the iCloud store.  I guess if you are doing all kinds of other store switching yourself it may be hard to figure out what is going on.

Comment: BTW I am not sure if the above is always how Core Data works but it seems to have been consistent since I started using iOS7.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Appreciate it